# Can't Login to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Getting the below error when trying to reach my WP login page....I have tried to look for whitespaces like crazy (2 days) and unable to correct the issue...still can't login...My site is up and running just fine...Someone please help...What other options do I have?

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wesleysoccer/webapps/wp/wp-content/themes/infocus/functions.php:1) in /home/wesleysoccer/webapps/wp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 868

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's whitespace at the beginning of your theme's functions.php file. If you can't find it, you can reset your theme to the default by changing your theme's directory name from infocus (changing it to anything else will work). That will deactivate the theme and allow you to at least log in.